# Play Youtube Videos automatically one after another in javascript

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, slider

I am having a requirement as follows,

1.I need to play Youtube videos( 10 or more videos in a sequence) one after another automatically using some javascript control.
  2.The User should be able to slide to next or previous video using slider buttons.
  3.If the current video ends up, the control should be able to pick next video and play it automatically.  I dont want this to happen with the help of any server controls in asp.net or ajax. But, would like to use only javascript and html elements or jquery if possible.

Can any one please suggest any links or useful information about javascript control to make this happen.

Any help is appreciated!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create normal slider, but add few functions to it's controls. Let's say, clicking on next, will stop current video, move slide to another and turn on new video. Everything is accessible through YouTube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference.

You can write your own slider or just choose of some written already:

- http://www.menucool.com/video-slider
- http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/
- http://www.slidesjs.com/
- http://wowslider.com/

Comment: flexislider helped me a lot!! Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

what you are searching for may be the "**player.cuePlaylist**" API function from Youtube. Read the "YouTube JavaScript Player API Reference": https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=zh-TW

Also note that recently Youtube changed the usage of it's API. You need to put your code on a webserver in order to function, because all calls from localhost are blocked.